# java instance not closed on task manager

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

i have created a Jframe in java

```
JFrame jf = new JFrame();
```

having converted it to jar file and running displays the JFrame window.

once i close the Jframe window it closes the jframe window closes, but the java.exe instance created on Task Manager is not closed, it is keep on running.

repeated execution of jar file creates many java.exe instance on task manager and it slows the computer.

i am doing a silly mistake here. how to close the java process created while closing the jar application from coding.

whether `system.exit(0)` will do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(int status)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) to terminate the JVM instance.

Its javadoc reads following:

> EXIT_ON_CLOSE (defined in JFrame): Exit the application using the
>   System exit method. Use this only in applications.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line of code if you have not done so already.

```
jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```